# Unrecognized selector sent to Core Data causes app crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a iPad app, using XCode 4.5, Storyboards, iOS 6 and MagicalRecord.  This code is causing the error, and I don't see why.  Both `aApptStart` and `selectedStartDate` are defined as DateTime.  So, what is causing this?

Here is the offending code:

```
- (IBAction)saveAppointment:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    AppointmentInfo *newAppointment = [AppointmentInfo createEntity];  //  create the entity

    NSLog(@"Selected start Date (save): %@", [self formatSelectedDate: selectedStartDate]); 

    newAppointment.aApptStart = selectedStartDate;  //  <------  causing the error
    newAppointment.aApptEnd= selectedEndDate;
    newAppointment.aTech = selectedTech;

    [localContext MR_saveNestedContexts];
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject
>   setAApptStart:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xee85dd0'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, what is causing this?

The error indicates that there is no property of that name in AppointmentInfo.

Well, does your NSManagedObject subclass (AppointmentInfo) declare the property aApptStart? Also, does a corresponding attribute for your entity exist (if the property is implemented `@dynamic`ally)?

I guess it would.... Maybe a typo? 
Can you show interface and implementation of AppointmentInfo?

Comment: I was in the process of restructuring my answer, which is a bit tedious cause I'm on my ipad. Didn't see your comment until now. What is undeeded (what does that even mean) and what wouldn't compile? And where is your answer? It's hard to give a concrete answer without more detail.

Comment: "It's hard to give a concrete answer without more detail" >> yes and this isnt an answer therefore :)

Comment: Mario... it was indeed a typo... thank you so much... Happy New Year to you and your family...

Comment: @Daij-Djan it was an answer since my guess was a typo. I admit I wasn't totally through with formatting and structuring my answer, but it answered the question ("what is causing this error". Answer: property not declared, and a -guessed- reason, a typo). You're quick with the downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Aparently your `[AppointmentInfo createEntity]` does not return an object of type `AppointmentInfo` but `NSManagedObject` and `NSManagedObject` does not provide a selector for `setAApptStart` meaning no setter for a propery `aApptStart`.

How exactly does your `+(AppointmentInfo*) createEntity` look like?